# batch inference for onnx opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, onnx, inference

I'm trying to inference a deep learning model loaded from `onnx` using `opencv`. My model input is as depicted below:
[image: extracted image by Netron]

as it is illustrated, the input size is `16 x 3 x 480 x 480`. I use code below for inference:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // work if set batch_sz = 1
    auto batch_sz = 16;

    string model_path = ".../best.onnx";
    cv::dnn::Net model = cv::dnn::readNet(model_path);

    Size im_sz(480, 480);
    
    Mat img0;
    resize(
        imread("...BMP"),
        img0,
        im_sz,
        0, 0,
        InterpolationFlags::INTER_CUBIC);

    vector<cv::Mat> ims;

    for (auto i = 0; i < batch_sz; i++)
        ims.push_back(img0);


    auto const len{ ims.size() };
    std::vector<cv::Mat> mats32f(len);

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < len; i++)
        ims[i].convertTo(mats32f[i], CV_32F, 1.f / 255);

    auto blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImages(
        mats32f, 1.0,
        mats32f[0].size());
    model.setInput(blob);
    vector<string> outLayerNames = model.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
    vector<Mat> result;

    model.forward(result, outLayerNames);

    // I also tried the code blow instead of above
    // result = model.forward(outLayerNames[0]);

    ... remaining part of codes
}
```

but I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAA98E4FD9 in ONNX_Test.exe: Microsoft
> C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000000762BCEA40.

It should be noted that the code works if I use `batch_sz = 1`. How can I run my model for `batch inference`?

following text `in my cmd` may be helpful:

OpenCV(4.6.0) Error: Assertion failed ((int)_numAxes == inputs[0].size()) in cv::dnn::PermuteLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes, file D:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.6.0-e24d1d7a25.clean\modules\dnn\src\layers\permute_layer.cpp, line 161
[ERROR:0@0.488] global D:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.6.0-e24d1d7a25.clean\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp (1171) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: [Permute]:(onnx_node!Transpose_201): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=1 outputs=0/1 blobs=0
[ERROR:0@0.488] global D:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.6.0-e24d1d7a25.clean\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp (1174) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 16 1 3 6 60 60 ]
[ERROR:0@0.488] global D:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.6.0-e24d1d7a25.clean\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp (1184) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\opencv4\src\4.6.0-e24d1d7a25.clean\modules\dnn\src\layers\permute_layer.cpp:161: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (int)_numAxes == inputs[0].size() in function 'cv::dnn::PermuteLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'